# how to use scanf with 2d array and how to pass the allocated array as a argument to function?

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

i have been searching and trieng to solve this problem for hours , i searched the internet and for some reason everytime i adjust a problem another one pops

basiclly i want to enetr values from user to a 2d array that it's size is unkown ( i also get it as an input) , and then i just want to pass this 2d array as an argument to a function like a regular 2d array ( arr[k][numElements] )

because the size of the 2d array in unkown i allocated the 2d array , then i tried to use scanf to enter valuse to the array but i get this error :

> subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

also when i try to pass the array to my functio i get errors 
(i prefer not to chane the function beacause i worked really hard to make it work lol)

```
int main()
{

    int numElements;
    int n; // number of elements
    int k; // number of parts

    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%d",&k);
    numElements=n/k;

    int length_of_array = k* numElements;

    int *arr = (int *)malloc( length_of_array * sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0 ; i<k ; i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<numElements ; j++){
        scanf("%d", arr[k][numElements]);
        }
    }



    int* output = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);


    divide(0, k - 1, output, numElements,k, arr);

    // Print merged array
    printf("\n________________________________________________________________\n");
    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        //scanf("%d",output+i);
        printf("%d ",*(output+i));
    }

}

//and this the function devide that i am trieng to pass the array to :
void divide(int l, int r, int* output, int numElements , int k ,  int arr[k][numElements] );
```

here i get the following error :

> expected 'int (*)[(sizetype)(numElements)]' but argument is of type
>   'int'

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int n, m; // number of elements

    scanf("%d",&n); // n no. of rows 
    scanf("%d",&m); // m no. of columns
    int arr[n][m]; //creating n*m memory spaces- runtime allocation

    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<m ; j++){
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]); //for each row takes n no. of column values
        }
    }

    int* output = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

    divide(0,n-1,arr); //passing lower index, upper index , the array

    // Print merged array
    printf("\n________________________________________________________________\n");
    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        //scanf("%d",output+i);
        printf("%d ",*(output+i));
    }
}
```

Comment: I modified only the array input part and function part as I don't know what do you want to calculate.

Comment: this won't work ! beacause the size is not known from the beganing i belieave

Comment: If you give here the question you want to solve then it would be more simple to understand.

Comment: it has nothing to do with the problem actually i just want to use scanf withe 2d allocated array :(

Comment: if you want to create n*n 2D array then the code will be: